# Rider does not open script while clicking error/log message in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rider

When I double click script/message/error in unity rider does not open it.
 Instead it shows me this message:

> Cannot find file 'D:\path_to_project--column'.

Comment: If you are using Unity 2019.2+, please update Rider package.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Ivan Shakov.

I am using different versions of Unity.
Rider updating to 2020.1.3 version helped me.